# jQuery animating droppable element does not animate it's 'target droppable area'

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, draggable, droppable

I have this code below which animates a DIV full of droppables into view when you start to drag a draggable element

```
    var droptions = {
            accept: '.sdPlayer',
            hoverClass: 'target',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var songId = (ui.draggable[0].id).substring(3);
                var mixId = (event.target.id).substring(4);
                alert('Song '+songId+' added to mix '+mixId);
            }           
        }
        $('.sdPlayer').draggable({
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 100,
            distance: 40,
            zIndex: 10, 
            start: function(){
                $('#mix-dropper').animate({top:122},200);
            },
            drag: function(){
                pl.dragging = true;
            },
            stop: function(){
                $('#mix-dropper').delay(500).animate({top:12},300);
                pl.dragging = false;
            }
        });
```

and the function that creates the div with the droppables:

```
// Insert user's mixes into #mix-dropper div below header
function mixDropper(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseURL+"mixes/getmixes/",
        success: function( response ){
            $( '#mix-dropper-mixes' ).html( response ); 
            //make newly appended divs droppable
            $( ".mix-dropper-mix" ).droppable(droptions)
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that you have to drag the draggable over the area that the `$('#mix-dropper-mix')` was in BEFORE it's parent `$('#mix-dropper')` was animated for it to work, I somehow need the draggable to recognise that the droppable has moved.

Can anyone tell me how that or some other solution can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (4 years too late), adding `refreshPositions: true,` to `$('.sdPlayer').draggable({` will make sort it out.

It took me far too long to figure that out.